# Find item name along with the seller id and buyer id such that the seller has sold the item to the buyer

Tags: sql

Hi IM trying to build a query for the following sentence for sql.

For each seller and each item sold by the seller, find the total amount sold.

I have 3 tables but not sure If i have to use them all. I have a feeling I need to use at least three tables to get this query but I keep getting an error. Also, I keep getting an error when I try to the following:

```
select selleruserid, itemid, sum(price) total
from sales_fact s
join items_dim i on i.itemid = s.itemid
join sellers_dim d on d.userid = s.selleruserid
group by selleruserid, itemid
```

I added a picture below of my tables.

[image: Tables]

Comment: `Also, I keep getting an error when I try to the following` What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

All the information you want is in the fact table, so the other tables do not seem necessary:

```
select sf.selleruserid, sf.itemid, sum(sf.price) as total
from sales_fact s
group by sf.selleruserid, sf.itemid;
```

You would need to join in the other tables if you needed other information from the dimension, such as the name.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this but I totally left out the sf.itemid and thats why it wasnt working.